# PyCrypto Decryption Mess

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto

So I'm trying to make a simple AES encrypt/decrypt system right now in Python... However when it decrypts it has a bunch of /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/ in front of the decrypted string.  How do I clean it and make it print only the plaintext.

My code is:

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

key = b'Sixteen byte key'
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(b'Attack at dawn...')
print (msg)
print (base64.b64encode(msg))

print (cipher.decrypt(msg))
```

The output of `decrypt` looks like this:

```
b'\xfb\xb8\xf0\xc3\xffH\xfc~\x19[\xecy?\xf8\xcc\x80Attack at dawn...'
```

Comment: can you share the output you're getting?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization vector (IV) is part of your encrypted message (`msg`), but the ciphertext itself should contain the IV. This means that you have to remove the IV before decrypting, i.e. like this:

```
cipher.decrypt(msg[16:])
```

Next issue is that you shouldn't use the same `AES` instance for encryption and decryption. The `AES` instance contains internal buffers that cannot be easily refreshed.

```
key = b'Sixteen byte key'

# encryption
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(b'Attack at dawn...')
print (msg)
print (base64.b64encode(msg))

# decryption
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, msg[:16])
print (cipher.decrypt(msg[16:]))
```

> However when it decrypts it has a bunch of /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/ in front of the decrypted string.

You have much luck that you see the decrypted string at all at the end. This is only because the IV is prepended to the message and the inner workings of the CFB mode of operation. If you would have used the CTR mode, this would have looked much different.

Answer (score -2):

The [docs](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.blockalgo.BlockAlgo-class.html#encrypt) state:

> That also means that you cannot reuse an object for encrypting or decrypting other data with the same key.

which is a bit cryptic, but if seems to mean you can't reuse `cipher` to decrypt. Also, I'm not sure why you concatenate `iv` to your encrypted message.

The code below works fine for me:

```
key = b'Sixteen byte key'
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
c = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
msg = c.encrypt('Attack at dawn...')
d = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
d.decrypt(msg)
```

Comment: The IV is prepended to the encrypted data so it will be available for decryption, it does not need to be secret. Only the encryption needs to be shared and can be used more than once. But the IV should be unique for each encryption with the same key so it is provided along with the encrypted data.